# Trailing args using Apache commons cli library

Tags: java, command-line-interface, apache-commons, apache-commons-cli

I found a command line utility in our code base where the author had written a homebrew command line parser, which involved more code than the utility itself did.  I decided to switch it to using Apache CLI and things are almost working.

The utility makes use of trailing args, so it'd look something like this:

```
util --argA=1 --argB=2 foo blah blarg
```

where "foo", "blah", and "blarg" are used as an argument.

Is there a way to handle this situation?  I'd rather not (and might not be empowered to) change the command line signature of this utility.

Comment: Disregard - I just stumbled across the getArgs() method from the CommandLine class, which appears to be exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Look at CommandLine.getArgList() or CommandLine.getArgs(), both return the "remaining" items from the commandline which were not handled by the options.

See [CommandLine javadocs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/apidocs/org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLine.html) for details.

Comment: The link is broken , you can use tis one https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/apidocs/org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLine.html

Comment: Adjusted the link, thanks!