# Commons CLI : recognize file name *.deca

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

I'm trying to use Apache Commons CLI to recognize the arguments of my java program. So, there is a bunch of options (such as "-p" as en example) but mostly, there is the name of the file that should be used as an input for the java program. Note that all options have no order restriction.

Example of the launch of the program :

`decac -p -r 5 test.deca`

I have no problems parsing the -p and -r (with argument "5") options but how do I create an option for "test.deca" knowing that it can be anything. It could also be something like pathTo/anotherTest.deca

Comment: @Aaron It seems it would solve my problem. Still wouldn't fix the problem in a more general way (multiple filenames) but should work for me! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, I find it strange this wasn't documented in their usage scenario

Comment: I think it fixes the problem in a general way : this list should contain any token that couldn't be parsed by the `CommandLineParser`, so for `decac -p other.file -r 5 test.deca and.another` it should contain `other.file`, `test.deca` and `and.another`.

Comment: @Aaron Yes yes but I was thinking more of an Option with regular expressions in order to use them as normal options. thanks again.

Comment: i think this option is added recently. try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449798/trailing-args-using-apache-commons-cli-library

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible out-of-the-box with ApacheCommonsCLI. You could do some tricks according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18344193/6825678) or you can use an argument option as described in the [apache CLI documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html)

```
Option decafile   = OptionBuilder.withArgName( "file.deca" )
                            .hasArg()
                            .withDescription(  "target deca file" )
                            .create( "decafile" );
```

That can be used later on with -dfile.deca or --decafile=file.deca

Comment: Not a solution to me as I can't change the way the arguments are entered. Thanks for the answer!